# how to handle files/directories with '@' in perforce

Tags: perforce

I have some folders with '@' in it.

I can't seem to make it work

```
>cd fmsn_adc_vs_cdc_clock_reset_integrity@fmsn_adc_vs                                           
>p4 rec -n ...
//depot/icm/proj/i10soc2/fmsn_lib/cdc/dev/fmsn_adc_vs/results/fmsn_adc_vs_cdc/consolidated_reports/fmsn_adc_vs_cdc_clock_reset_integrity%40fmsn_adc_vs/spyglass.log - can't reconcile filename with wildcards [@#%*]. Use -f to force reconcile.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
... - no file(s) to reconcile.                                                                                                                                                                                                            

>cd ..                                                                                                                                  >p4 rec -n 'fmsn_adc_vs_cdc_clock_reset_integrity@fmsn_adc_vs/...'                                                                                                                                                                     
Invalid changelist/client/label/date '@fmsn_adc_vs/...'.                                                                                                                                                                                  
No file(s) to reconcile.
```

How can we handle files/directories with '@' ?

Is there any documentation I can refer to?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_reconcile.html note the list of special filename characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error message gives you the exact answer:

```
Use -f to force reconcile.
```

Just add `-f` to the command you tried the first time:

```
p4 rec -n -f ...
```

This will automatically translate the `@` to `%40` in the depot path when it opens the file for add.  From that point on, if you need to refer to that file by name, use `%40` in place of `@`.  It will still have the `@` in its local path.